# IOS CoreNFC framework - tagID visible in debugger - how to get to it via code

Tags: ios, nfc

Using the Apple Core NFC framework I can see in the debugger XCODE 9 under session there is an array foundTags[] and a value of tagID. For the life of me I can't figure out how to get to these values in the code. It seems to be non documented at the moment, but I can see one other apps in the apple store they are getting hold of the value.  Any ideas would be welcome.  I have attached a picture of the debugger and the values I am after.

session is NFCNDEFReaderSession and xcode suggests it does not know foundTags?

I have a working application reading the messages and payloads fine, but can't seem to get to these values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone else has trouble negotiating objects the answer to this was to use [Swift KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html) simply used the ObjectName.value(forKey:" what you are looking for") and found them easy enough.  In may case as an example session.value(forKey:"_foundTags") gave me the values I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for anyone finding this:

We did have UID and types in our IOS NFC app but we have noticed since the latest build 11.2 on the iPhone these values are being suppressed.  Hopefully one day they will just support it in the API.  Our current version of PROX NFC Tag just shows unavailable so will remove on the next version until they appear again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement `NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcndefreadersessiondelegate) to get the list of NDEF messages found by the reader session

Comment: Hi - thank you - I have implemented it as such: class NFCScanView: BaseViewController, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate { - and can get the messages fine. Just cant get to these values - sure doing something really stupid

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/hansemannn/iOS11-NFC-Example/blob/master/README.md#getting-started) an example of how you can fetch them

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I have a working app that is fine getting hold of the messages and payloads.  I am effectively trying to get hold of the tag UID, which seems to be visible now as you can see in my picture.  The values seem hidden though via the code.